# Inserting Many HDF5 Datasets Very Slow

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

There is a dramatic slowdown when inserting many datasets into a group.

I have found that the slowdown point is proportional to the length of the name and number of datasets. A larger dataset does take a bit longer to insert but it didn't affect when the slowdown occurred.

The following example exaggerates the length of the name just to illustrate the point without waiting a long time.

- Python 3
- HDF5 Version 1.8.15 (1.10.1 gets even slower)
- h5py version: 2.6.0

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import time

hdf = h5py.File('dummy.h5', driver='core', backing_store=False)
group = hdf.create_group('some_group')

dtype = np.dtype([
    ('name', 'a20'),
    ('x', 'f8'),
    ('y', 'f8'),
    ('count', 'u8'),
])
ds = np.array([('something', 123.4, 567.8, 20)], dtype=dtype)

long_name = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*50

t = time.time()
size = 1000*25
for i in range(1, size + 1):
    group.create_dataset(
        long_name+str(i),
        (len(ds),),
        maxshape=(None,),
        chunks=True,
        compression='gzip',
        compression_opts=9,
        shuffle=True,
        fletcher32=True,
        dtype=dtype,
        data=ds
    )
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        dt = time.time() - t
        t = time.time()
        print('{0} / {1} -  Rate: {2:.1f} inserts per second'.format(i, size, 1000/dt))

hdf.close()
```

Output:

```
1000 / 25000 -  Rate: 1590.9 inserts per second
2000 / 25000 -  Rate: 1770.0 inserts per second
...
17000 / 25000 -  Rate: 1724.7 inserts per second
18000 / 25000 -  Rate: 106.3 inserts per second
19000 / 25000 -  Rate: 66.9 inserts per second
20000 / 25000 -  Rate: 66.9 inserts per second
21000 / 25000 -  Rate: 67.5 inserts per second
22000 / 25000 -  Rate: 68.4 inserts per second
23000 / 25000 -  Rate: 47.7 inserts per second
24000 / 25000 -  Rate: 42.0 inserts per second
25000 / 25000 -  Rate: 39.8 inserts per second
```

Again, I exaggerated the length of the name just to reproduce the issue quickly. 
**In my problem the length of the name is about 25 characters and the slowdown point occurs after ~700k datasets are in a group.**
After ~1.4M datasets it gets even slower.

Why is this happening?

Is there a solution/remedy?

Comment: In addition to John Readey's comment: this is not the intended use case for HDF5 and it is hard to obtain good performance for many (thousands, say) datasets. Consider consolidating your data in fewer larger datasets.

Comment: The problem is that I have a specific schema to follow and many tools that depend on that schema. Certain conditions are generating way more data than planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using libver='latest' when you open the file.  Recent versions of the library vastly improved the speed for adding items to a group, but for compatibility reasons this is only enabled with the above option.

Comment: Awesome! libver='latest' made a big difference. I was able to insert 5M datasets at constant rate from my example above. However, that was "in memory" and when I use actual data writing to disk it still slows down by ~30x after ~1M datasets. Even though it still slows down; it's better than before. Do you have any other tips?