# h5py create_dataset loop slow

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to create a hdf5 file where each dataset is a 90x18 numpy array.  I'm looking to create 2704332 total datasets for the file with an approximate final size of 40 GB.

```
with h5py.File('allDaysData.h5', 'w') as hf:
    for x in list:
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        hf.create_dataset(x, data=currentData)
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(end-start)
```

When running this the create_dataset command takes no longer then .0004 seconds in the beginning.  Once the file hits around 6 GB it abruptly switches to taking 0.08 seconds per dataset.

Is there some sort of limit on datasets for hdf5 files?

Comment: How much physical memory do you have? And what's your OS?

Comment: Running on on an AWS EC2 m4.10xlarge instance with Amazon Linux. (160 GB RAM)

Comment: If all datasets are of the same shape and dtype it would be much better (and faster) to create one dataset with shape (2704332,90,18) with a proper chunking specification (and chunk cache size), according to your write and read conditions. If you do it this way it should be possible to reach your sequential disk-io speed. Please give more information about how do you want to read your data afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023488/inserting-many-hdf5-datasets-very-slow)

In this answer, you can see the performance of `create_dataset` is decreasing with the increasing of iterations. As `h5py` stores data in special structure, I think it is because `h5py` need more time to index the datasets.

There are two solutions, One is to use key word `libver='latest'`. It will improve the performance significantly even though the generated file will be incompatible with old ones. Second one is to aggregate your arrays into several aggregations. For example, aggregate every 1024 arrays into one.